# What are the exact differences between CSLA for silverlight and windows?

Tags: silverlight, csla

How CSLA for silverlight and windows differ? What are exact differences in terms of features?

Comment: It wouldn't have hurt to provide this link: http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/Default.aspx#

Answer (score 1):

The following [document](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/overviewofcslanet36forwindowsandsilverlight.aspx) outlines all the differences in feature set between silverlight (lite version of CSLA) and the Winforms/asp.net version (full version of CSLA).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))